# Hi, I deployed an app on fly io with docker and can not connect to postgresdb. Localy everything works just fine. any help would be appriciated thanks

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, docker, asp.net-core

fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]An error occurred using the connection to database 'dash007_reactivities?sslmode=disable' on server fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100] An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Persistence.DataContext'.
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while performing SSL handshake

```
          services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
                  {
                  var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

                      string connStr;

                      if (env == "Development")
                      {
                        connStr = config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"); // DefaultConnection string must match appsettings.Development.json
                      }
                      else
                      {
                       
                        var connUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DATABASE_URL");
                   
                        connUrl = connUrl.Replace("postgres://", string.Empty);

                        var pgUserPass = connUrl.Split("@")[0];
                        var pgHostPortDb = connUrl.Split("@")[1];
                        var pgHostPort = pgHostPortDb.Split("/")[0];
                        var pgDb = pgHostPortDb.Split("/")[1];
                        var pgUser = pgUserPass.Split(":")[0];
                        var pgPass = pgUserPass.Split(":")[1];
                        var pgHost = pgHostPort.Split(":")[0];
                        var pgPort = pgHostPort.Split(":")[1];

             connStr = $"Server={pgHost};Port={pgPort};User Id={pgUser};Password=    {pgPass};Database={pgDb};";
                      }

                      options.UseNpgsql(connStr);
                    });


Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080


COPY "Reactivities.sln" "Reactivities.sln"
COPY "API/API.csproj" "API/API.csproj"
COPY "Application/Application.csproj" "Application/Application.csproj"
COPY "Persistence/Persistence.csproj" "Persistence/Persistence.csproj"
COPY "Domain/Domain.csproj" "Domain/Domain.csproj"
COPY "Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj" "Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj"

RUN dotnet restore "Reactivities.sln" 


COPY . .
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "API.dll" ]



appsettings:

"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=host.docker.internal; Port=5432; User Id=admin; Password=password; Database=reactivitiesDB"
    
  },

  "TokenKey": "test"






fly.toml:



app = "dash007-reactivities"
kill_signal = "SIGINT"
kill_timeout = 5
primary_region = "ams"
processes = []

[build]
  image = "dash007/reactivities:latest"

[env]
  ASPNETCORE_URLS = "http://+:8080"
  Cloudinary__ApiKey = "test"
  Cloudinary__CloudName = "test"

[experimental]
  allowed_public_ports = []
  auto_rollback = true
  private_network = true

[[services]]
  http_checks = []
  internal_port = 8080
  processes = ["app"]
  protocol = "tcp"
  script_checks = []
  [services.concurrency]
    hard_limit = 25
    soft_limit = 20
    type = "connections"

  [[services.ports]]
    force_https = true
    handlers = ["http"]
    port = 80

  [[services.ports]]
    handlers = ["tls", "http"]
    port = 443

  [[services.tcp_checks]]
    grace_period = "1s"
    interval = "15s"
    restart_limit = 0
    timeout = "2s"


I tried everything and it does not work.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as you.  Ultimately, I decided that my app wasn't connecting to the fly.io postgres database.  I finally figured out that the parsed info from the environment variable was not correct for NpgSqp.  I was able to get it to connect by hard coding the pgHost to appName-db.internal where appName is the name of your app in fly.io.  I think for this example the instructor used da-course for the app name so the pgHost would be da-course-db.internal.

Hopefully this helps.